# Как заставить чужой скрипт открываться в новом окне (вкладке)?

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Нужно этот скрипт заставить открываться в новом окне (вкладке). Это скрипт сервиса отображения посетителей (карта посетителей в мире).

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.amung.us/map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">WAU_map('mtyqtwkyseeo', 240, 135, 'textbook', 'star-yellow')</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вам window.open ?

```
<a href="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX" target="_blank">link name</a>
```

вот, всё ...

Answer (score 0):

Добавить свойство `target="_blank"` в тег, скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно открыть через JS, то как-то так:

```js
function timer(){
  var interval = setInterval(step, 1000);
  var count = 5;
  var view = document.querySelector('strong');
  function step(){
    if(count == 0){
      document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = 'Открываем!';
      window.open('http://google.co.uk/', '_blank'); // Вот оно - второй аргумент, установленный в `_blank` откроет новую вкладку!
      clearInterval(interval);
    }else{
      count--;
      view.innerHTML = count;
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', timer);
```

```html
<div>Я отрою новую вкладку через <strong>5</strong> сек.!</div>
```

P. S. В этом примере не сработает, т.к. в фрейме нельзя открывать окна таким образом без особого разрешения, вот пруф: https://jsfiddle.net/jks8epgm/ (только надо разрешить отрыть, т.к. обычно браузеры блокируют этот финт ушами. Всё из-за нехороших человекаф, редисок!).